# NodeJS + ExpressJS, unable to read environment variable

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting a variable in Express.js as follows: `app.set('HOST', 'demo.sample.com');`. However, if I try to read this variable, I get `undefined` as the output. I am reading the variable using `process.env.HOST`. Nevertheless, if I try to read it using `app.get('HOST')`, I get the correct value.

I cannot use `app.get('HOST')` since I am reading the variable in another file too — a file that does not contain a reference to the Express.js app variable.

How do I get the value using `process.env.HOST`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`app.set()` doesn't set environment variables, it's just a convenience method offered by Express to be used together with `app.get()`.

If you want to set an environment variable in your JS code, use this:

```
process.env.HOST = 'demo.sample.com';
```

Comment: So do you mean to say that `app.set` and `process.env` do not work in conjuction with each other?

Comment: Oh, I skipped that part. Disregard my answer then. process.env is not related to Express at all, it reads system variables.

Comment: Just wanted to add my twocents on this : 

I wanted to get an "if on heroku" so I did this : 

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {}

Using expressjs

Answer (score 1):

Update: process.env only reads your operating system environment settings. To setup express vars, use app.get() and app.set(), like in the other answer.

Is your HOST variable set at all? It's usually set as HOSTNAME.

```
[zlatko@droplet ~]$ node
> process.env.HOST
undefined
> process.env.HOSTNAME
'droplet.zlayer.net'
>
```

You could set it manually in Bash (I assume you use bash) though:

```
[zlatko@droplet ~]$ export HOST=$HOSTNAME
[zlatko@droplet ~]$ node
> process.env.HOST
'droplet.zlayer.net'
```

>

The export line could have been a literal, ie:

```
export HOSTNAME=myhostname.myserver.com
```

Comment: actually, `host` here is just an example. I have other variables too that are specific to my project and they are not set too. So host or hostname does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you will need to set the environment variable for the bash/shell
in order to call it from the APP.
Try setting the environment variable using export NODE_ENV='production' or 'development' then configure your app using app.configure 'production',() -> and try again